# PyDrive: cannot write file to specific GDrive folder

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to copy files from a local machine to a specific folder in GDrive using PyDrive. If the target folder does not yet exist, I want to create it. Here is the relevant section of my code:

```
gfile = drive.CreateFile({'title':'dummy.csv', 
        'mimeType':'text/csv',
        'parent': tgt_folder_id})
gfile.SetContentFile('dummy.csv') 
gfile.Upload() # Upload it
```

I am definitely creating/finding the target folder correctly, and the tgt_folder_id is correct, but PyDrive always writes the file to the **root folder** of my Google Drive, not the target folder I've specified via the 'parent' parameter.

What am I doing wrong  here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK, looks like this is how you do it:

```
gfile = drive.CreateFile({'title':'dummy.csv', 'mimeType':'text/csv',
        "parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink","id": tgt_folder_id}]})
```

The "parents" map is used in the Google Drive SDK, which PyDrive is supposed to wrap.  But the very few examples I've seen with PyDrive use "parent" and don't seem to work.

Anyway, hope this helps anybody else who hits the same problem.

Comment: Excellent self answered question. I would be very stuck without this :)

Comment: @Chris Webster, Did you by any chance figure out how to save files in subfolders? The thing is that 

`file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:       
    print ('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))`

gives only ids for folders located in the root, but not subfolders

Answer (score 1):

Ahoj @i-am-nik, to list subfolders you may use slightly altered line:

```
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': 'trashed=false', 'maxResults': 10}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
  print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
```

This way it will list both folders and subfolders (of course, if you have many files, you may need to change maxResults value or add narrowing query.